# Statement in TypeError module is not letting function work without second parameter

Tags: javascript, typeerror, prototype-programming

I want to add a function to String object which searches all string and returns indexes of the word we want to find. When I don't use `startIndex` parameter it shouldn't throw a second error, because this statement `typeof startIndex !== "undefined"` let this function work without `startIndex`. Please correct me and thanks for the help.

```
String.prototype.allIndexOf = allIndexOfFunction;

function allIndexOfFunction(string, startIndex) {
    startIndex = startIndex || 0
    var indexArr = [];
    var sIndex = 0;
    var baseString = this.concat();
    if (typeof string === "string" && typeof startIndex === "number" && startIndex >= 0) {
        while(sIndex !== -1){
            sIndex = baseString.indexOf(string, startIndex);
            if(sIndex !== -1){
                indexArr.push(sIndex);
                startIndex = startIndex + sIndex +1;
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        if (typeof string !== "string") {
            throw "First parameter must be a string type";
        }
        else if (typeof startIndex !== "number" || typeof startIndex !== "undefined") {
            throw "Second parameter must be a number type";
        }
        else if (startIndex <= 0) {
            throw "Second parameter must be equal or bigger than 0";
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    return indexArr;
}
//TEST
var a = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit Buzz, consectetur Buzz elit. Quod vero voluptatibus Buzz error deserunt libero, Buzz incidunt Buzz facere! A!";
var test = a.allIndexOf("Buzz");
console.log("Searching indexes of \"Buzz\" word in string -> " + a);
console.log(test);
```

Comment: i am not getting any type error by running that script http://jsbin.com/qehasupuru/edit?html,js,console,output which browser you are running it in

Comment: I think the OP is saying he is hitting the throw but isn't expecting to when there is no second parameter.

Comment: Given you are doing `startIndex = startIndex || 0`, the condition `typeof startIndex !== "undefined"` will always be true

Comment: That is a very weird implementation. Why are you checking for type errors in the end, after your code already ran? Why are you `throw`ing strings only to immediately `catch` them?

Comment: What error message are you actually getting? Notice that your question title is undecipherable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple issue. Your logic is not quite right - you need AND rather than OR:

Change your one line to:

`else if (typeof startIndex !== "number" && typeof startIndex !== "undefined") {`

Also, since you default to 0 if the startIndex is not defined, then you don't need this second condition test at all.

You can see it running as expected here:

```js
String.prototype.allIndexOf = allIndexOfFunction;

function allIndexOfFunction(string, startIndex) {
  startIndex = startIndex || 0
  var indexArr = [];
  var sIndex = 0;
  var baseString = this.concat();
  if (typeof string === "string" && typeof startIndex === "number" && startIndex >= 0) {
    while(sIndex !== -1){
      sIndex = baseString.indexOf(string, startIndex);
      if(sIndex !== -1){
        indexArr.push(sIndex);
        startIndex = startIndex + sIndex +1;
      }
    }
  }
  try {
    if (typeof string !== "string") {
      throw "First parameter must be a string type";
    }
    else if (typeof startIndex !== "number") {
      throw "Second parameter must be a number type";
    }
    else if (startIndex <= 0) {
      throw "Second parameter must be equal or bigger than 0";
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  return indexArr;
}
//TEST
var a = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit Buzz, consectetur Buzz elit. Quod vero voluptatibus Buzz error deserunt libero, Buzz incidunt Buzz facere! A!";
var test = a.allIndexOf("Buzz");
console.log("Searching indexes of \"Buzz\" word in string -> " + a);
console.log(test);
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much. Simple mistakes cost most time.

Comment: No problem, Hemes. I updated the answer... since the second condition is really not needed if you default to 0.